# Deploying django app to heroku - can't find new uploaded files

Tags: python, django, heroku

I build this site "https://bookzd.herokuapp.com" to download books
but when i choose a book and try to downloaded it can't be downloaded, it says 404 not found.
I did run Django app locally and it work fine.

I'm using selenium to download books and save it to "media/books"

models.py

```
book = models.FileField(upload_to='books', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
```

view.py

```
# view that download the book.
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'book'
    
    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        _downloadBook(pk)
        return Book.objects.get(pk=pk)

def _downloadBook(pk):
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if book.book: return
    bookData = downloadBook(book.bookURL)
    book.cover = bookData['cover']
    book.lang = bookData['lang']
    book.author = bookData['author']
    book.file = bookData['file'] # book type pdf/epub
    book.year = bookData['year']
    book.book = bookData['book'] # here the book "books/book_name.pdf/epub"
    book.save()
```

The problem not in my django app because i run it locally and it work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "upload files to database"? Files typically wouldn't be stored in a database.

Comment: The files not sorted i tried the django app locally it worked fine but deployed it to heroku the files won't show up

Comment: Please read [ask]. Clarity is very important. How are you trying to store the files? Are you putting them in a database, as your first comment suggests? Or are you trying to put save them somewhere as files? If so, where? And how? A [mre] Would be helpful.